# How to spin wheel after specified time is reached?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on small project of lucky draw number, am able to spin the wheel after user clicks button but not able to do it automatically, means I want to show count Down after time is reached wheel spins. I have used set Interval method but its not working.

```js
  window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 10 * 1,
        display = document.querySelector('#count');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
  
function startTimer(duration, display) {
var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    
 
    setInterval(function () 
 {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = "Wheel Will Spin After: "+minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            //timer = duration;
   spin();
   if(timer<=-1)
  {
   display.textContent = "Wheel Will Spin After: ";
  }
        }
  
    }, 1000);
 var colors = ["#B8D430", "#3AB745", "#029990", "#3501CB",
               "#2E2C75", "#673A7E", "#CC0071", "#F80120",
               "#F35B20", "#FB9A00", "#FFCC00", "#FEF200","#FEFAAA","#FEFA1A"];
  var restaraunts = ["1", "2", "3", "4","5", "6", "7", "8","9", "10", "11", "12","13","14"];
  
  var startAngle = 0;
  var arc = Math.PI / 7;
  
  var spinTimeout = null;
  
  var spinArcStart = 10;
  var spinTime = 0;
  var spinTimeTotal = 0;
  
  var ctx;
  
  function draw() {
    drawRouletteWheel();
  }
  
  function drawRouletteWheel() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("wheelcanvas");
    if (canvas.getContext) {
      var outsideRadius = 200;
      var textRadius = 160;
      var insideRadius = 125;
      
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
      
      
      ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      
      ctx.font = 'bold 20px Times New Roman';
      
      for(var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        var angle = startAngle + i * arc;
        ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];
        
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
        ctx.arc(250, 250, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();
        
        ctx.save();
        ctx.shadowOffsetX = -1;
        ctx.shadowOffsetY = -1;
        ctx.shadowBlur    = 0;
        ctx.shadowColor   = "rgb(220,220,220)";
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.translate(250 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius, 250 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
        ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
        var text = restaraunts[i];
        ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0);
        ctx.restore();
      } 
      
      //Arrow
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
      ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
      ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
      ctx.lineTo(250 + 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
      ctx.lineTo(250 + 0, 250 - (outsideRadius - 13));
      ctx.lineTo(250 - 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
      ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
      ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
  
  function spin() {
    spinAngleStart = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
    spinTime = 5;
    spinTimeTotal = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 2000;
    rotateWheel();
  }
  
  function rotateWheel() {
    spinTime += 20;
    if(spinTime >= spinTimeTotal) {
      stopRotateWheel();
      return;
    }
    var spinAngle = spinAngleStart - easeOut(spinTime, 0, spinAngleStart, spinTimeTotal);
    startAngle += (spinAngle * Math.PI / 180);
    drawRouletteWheel();
    spinTimeout = setTimeout('rotateWheel()', 10);
  }
  
  function stopRotateWheel() {
    clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
    var degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
    var arcd = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
    var index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.font = 'bold 12px sans-serif';
    var text = restaraunts[index]
    //ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10);
 //window.location = "navto://"+restaraunts[index]+"_stack";
 //alert(text);
 document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=text;
    ctx.restore();
  }
  
  function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
    var ts = (t/=d)*t;
    var tc = ts*t;
    return b+c*(tc + -3*ts + 3*t);
  }
  
  draw();
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id= "count" class="category_heading" >Wheel Will Spin After: </div>
<div id= "msg" class="category_heading" >LUCKY NUMBER IS : </div>
<canvas id="wheelcanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is too broad with no sign of what you are doing. Try posting code you have tried, how it is supposed to work and what goes wrong.

Comment: You really need to show your code if you expect someone to be able to answer your question. How are we supposed to know why your interval method isn't working otherwise?

Comment: check this https://codepen.io/zadvorsky/pen/xzhBw

Comment: sir, I have added code snippet i am not understanding errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the solution. Replace

```
spinTimeout = setTimeout('rotateWheel()', 10);
```

with

```
spinTimeout = setTimeout( rotateWheel, 10);
```

The reason the error occurs is because `rotateWheel` is a nested function within the `startTimer` function and not in global scope. The code snippet `"rotateWheel()"` which is passed to setTimeout as text is compiled into a function in global scope which when executed can't find the `rotateWheel` function. Replacing the text with a function reference (which is in scope) removes the need to compile the source text in the first place.

In general avoid using JavaScript source snippets within code unless it is a quick and dirty solution to something no-one else is going to see :-).

I take it this is work in progress and there may be more bugs before the code is complete. Good luck.

---

In response to comment, the wheel continues to rotate because `spin()` is being called during each interval timer callback after `timer` goes negative.

```
 var timerId = setInterval(function () 
    {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = "Wheel Will Spin After: "+minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            //timer = duration;
            spin();
            clearInterval( timerId)
            display.textContent = "Wheel Will Spin After: ";
        }`
    }, 1000);
```

The solution above is to call `spin` once and then stop the interval timer. Notice that `if( --timer < 0)` followed by `if(timer<=-1)` effectively test the same condition for integers which means the second test is not required.

Comment: thank you so much. that was very much helpful. The Wheel isn't stopping it is in loop.